# how to change script tag data using javscript

Tags: javascript

i want to change script data using javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <button id="loadData">Check</button>

    <button id="change">Change Data</button>

    <script id="datas">

data = {
    key: "ABCDEFG",
    balance: "100",
   }; // change this data using id
   
   </script>

   <script>

//    loadDataButton = document.getElementById("loadData");

document.getElementById("loadData").addEventListener("click", function () {

    alert(data.key);

});

document.getElementById("change").addEventListener("click", function () {

document.getElementById("datas").innerHTML = `data = {
    key: "BCSD123",
    balance: "200",
   };`;  // changed new data but till giving me key ABCDEFG

alert(data.key);

});
      </script>


</body>
</html>
```

this method change only for show but i click on check button than giving me old data .. this problem i am facing . i want data key after change script tag data **BCSD123**

Comment: Why not reassign `data`: `data = { key: "BCSD123", balance: "200", };`? The `<script>` tag doesn't execute again after you've changed its contents.

Comment: There's no need to change the *contents* of `data` in a `<script>` tag. Just access the variable object `data` and modify its keys values using `data.key = "N3W1D"; data.balance = "200";`

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to modify the ***contents*** of a `<script>` tag.

- modify the `data`'s key values using a [new Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)
- preview the object internals setting a trap in the Setter of your proxy object
- reflect the changes onto to target `data` object:

```js
// Some initial data:
var data = { key: "SOM31D", balance: "0" }; 


// Reflector:
const react = (ob, cb, _r) => Object.assign(new Proxy(ob, {
  set: (...arg) => (_r = Reflect.set(...arg), cb?.(ob), _r)
}), ob);

// Use like:

const previewData = (ob) => {
  document.querySelector("#previewData").value = JSON.stringify(ob, null, 2);
};

// Whenever `data` inits or changes, do something with that object:
const dataProxy = react(data, previewData);

document.querySelector("#loadData").addEventListener("click", function() {
  Object.assign(dataProxy, { key: "ABCDEFG", balance: "100" });
});

document.querySelector("#changeData").addEventListener("click", function() {
  Object.assign(dataProxy, { key: "BCSD123", balance: "200" });
});
```

```html
<button id="loadData">Load data</button>
<button id="changeData">Change data</button><br>
<textarea rows=5 id="previewData"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to change data's value through dynamics, you can change the value of variable in the callback function.

```js
document.getElementById("change").addEventListener("click", function() {
  data.key = "BCSD123";
  alert(data.key);
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).